# Netezza SQL For Loop

Tags: sql, loops, for-loop, netezza

I have the following query Which I will call query1:

```
with a as (
select customer_key as cust,
sum(sales)*1.0/4 as avg_sales
sum(returns)*1.0/4 as avg_return
count(distinct order_key)*1.04 as avg_num_orders
from orders_table
where purch_year between 2011 and 2014
group by cust
order by random()
),

b as (
select *
from a
where avg_num_orders > .25
limit 100000
)

select case 
       when avg_num_orders <= 1 then 'Low'
       when avg_num_orders between 1 and 4 then 'Medium'
       when avg_num_orders > 4 then 'High'
   end as estimated_frequency,
   count(cust) as num_purchasers_year,
   sum(avg_num_orders) as num_orders_year,
   avg(avg_num_orders) as avg_num_order_year,
   sum(avg_sales) as avg_sales_year,
   sum(avg_total_return) as avg_return_year,
   avg_sales_year/num_orders_year as AOV,
   avg_sales_year/num_purchasers_year as ACS,
   stddev(avg_sales) as sales_stddev
from b
where avg_num_orders > .25
group by estimated_frequency
order by  estimated_frequency;
```

I want to write code that does the following (this is what does not work, I have provided pseudocode). I do not have permission to create a procedure.

```
Create table temp1
for i in 1..100 loop
insert into temp1 the result of QUERY1
end loop
```

then

```
select estimated_frequency,
       avg(acs),
       avg(sales_stddev)
from temp1
group by estimated_frequency
```

Essentially, I want to run query1 100 times, and store the results in a table called temp1, and then compute some averages on temp1 once i am all said and done.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

*I would have added this as a comment but don't have enough rep.*

The only option I can see is to do this outside of Netezza and write your loop in a batch file/shell script/Python script/...

I tried the following but note that this does NOT work because the random number is generated only once and then reused, so you get 100 identical samples.

```
-- Test view which gives some random data from an existing table.
create view my_view as 
    select 
        m.*
    from my_table t
    join (
        select (floor(random()*10)+1)::integer rand_id -- assuming I have ids from 1 to 10
    ) x on x.rand_id = t.id;

create table results (id integer, data double precision);

insert into results
    select v.*
    from my_view v
    cross join table(generate_series(1,100));
```

Generate_series is a user-defined table function that you can get from [the Enzee Community website](https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/wikis/home?lang=en-us#!/wiki/W361a40e2ccf0_43c7_b802_e51fcadaec6b/page/C__%20UDX%20Examples).